# Summation of lengths on unit circle

Tags: geometry

Let $P_1$, $P_2$,...,$P_n$ be points on a circle of radius 1, centered at $O$. Let $G$ be the point such that $\overrightarrow{OG}=\frac{\overrightarrow{OP_1}+\overrightarrow{OP_2}+\dots+\overrightarrow{OP_n}}{n}$ and let $d=OG$. Express $\sum_{1\le i < j\le n}(P_i P_j)^2$ in terms of $n$ and $d$.

Comment: It appears that $G=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nP_i$; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at one of these squared distances by itself:

\begin{align*}
s_{ij}&=(P_iP_j)^2=(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2
=x_i^2-2x_ix_j+x_j^2+y_i^2-2y_iy_j+y_j^2\\
&=(x_i^2+y_i^2)+(x_j^2+y_j^2)-2x_ix_j-2y_iy_j
=2(1-x_ix_j-y_iy_j)
\end{align*}

So the sum of all these squared distances is

$$a=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(P_iP_j)^2
=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}s_{ij}
=n^2-n-\sum_{1\le i\ne j\le n}(x_ix_j+y_iy_j)
$$

Let's compare that to the squared distance to the center of gravity $G$:

\begin{align*}
d^2&=
\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}n\right)^2+
\left(\frac{y_1+y_2+\dots+y_n}n\right)^2
\\&=\frac1{n^2}\left(
(x_1^2+y_1^2)+\dots+(x_n^2+y_n^2)+
2(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+\dots+2(x_{n-1}x_n+y_{n-1}y_n)
\right)
\\&=\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\sum_{1\le i\neq j\le n}(x_ix_j+y_iy_j)
\end{align*}

So I'd say the quantity you want is

$$a=n^2(1-d^2)$$

unless I made a mistake. Please check with some simple numbers.